# Looking for web service.solution for embedded Linux/C platform

Tags: c, web, service, embedded

I hope I can expose web sercices APIs from my embedded Linux device. By doing that I can then write standalone Windows application that involves these APIs to get/put data from/to my device.  Since the client GUI for some reason has to be written in Gtk, that means I plan to use c for the client side, no Java here. On the server side, since it's an embedded Linux and all my business logics already implemented in a lot of c code, so I also hope that I can use c to write any web servive code on the server side.

I heard there exists Restful and SOAP, I searched google and grabed some ideas about them. I prefer to be simple but not sure whether Restful good enough to suit my task (remember I am not going to create web clients and I have only application clients).  Do you have a suggestion on the topic?

And, even I choosed the style of web servive (Rest or SOAP), I think I still need a framework for my platform. The requirements of having to use C language seems limited the list to two options, the Apache axis2/c and gSOAP. Does them can be cross compiled to ARM Linux? And which one is more suitable? Any suggestion from you will be highly appreciated!

-woody

Comment: A REST API is *very* easy to make: Make a server program that listens for connections on a specific port. Handle HTTP `GET` requests from accepted connections. The "path" in the `GET` request is the API "call", and you send the appropriate data (as XML or JSON). Making a simple HTTP 1.0 server is not hard, and there are hundreds of examples all over the 'net. You can easily hide your server behind a proper (small footprint) web-server acting as a proxy.

Comment: You should edit your question to improve it. What kind of device are you developing for? What exact web service do you want it to give?

Answer (score 1):

You could use some HTTP server library in C, like e.g. [libonion](http://www.coralbits.com/libonion/), in your embedded Linux device. It probably is the best solution (but you should be sure that your application is reliable enough to run continuously for weeks without crashing).

You could also run some light web server (e.g. [lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/)) and have your program be a [FastCGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fastcgi) or [CGI](http://www.w3.org/CGI/) application. This approach probably makes sense only if your device needs to also serve web pages for some other purposes.

<sup>We have no exact idea about your device and your application (and the web services you want).</sup>

Comment: But... CGI is not web service, right?

Comment: CGI is an old way to implement some Web thing. You could use it for web services, but you probably don't want to (since a CGI forks a process for every HTTP request)

Comment: Hi, Basile, but you suggested the CGI way to me, so I did  not get the point... If I dont want to write an web server (despite how easy it is with help of 3rd party libraries, I could take a lot time to make it stable), also not prefer to go the CGI way, what should I do?

Comment: Using the `libonion` is probably the most appropriate. But if your device is very occasionally used thru HTTP (e.g. my home router), and/or if it needs to serve web pages for other purposes, the `lighttpd` + `FastCGI` (or old `CGI`) solution might make sense.

Comment: The data I want to exchange between clients and my device are quite large, not like those something in a 'form', so I want to look for non-cgi solution.  Thanks.